# How to match a field and get its objectId from MongoDB using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, collections

I tried the below code to match name and get the _id from MongoDB using Node.js. But I am unable to fetch. Can someone figure out the mistake in my code. Student is my schema model name

```
Student.aggregate([ 
  { $match : { name: "ABCD" }},
  {$project: {_id: 1} } 
  ], function (err, doc) {
        console.log(doc+'   agregation');
  for(var i in doc){
  console.log(doc[i]._id)
  }
      }
);
```

Comment: That appears to be missing a `}` to close the `$match` stage.

Comment: Your code looks fine, can you give more detail than what you trying to achieve with this query, or are you getting any error?

Comment: I am getting output as an empty array

Comment: I am trying to fetch the _id from student collection by giving student name. Student in the code is my schema name